# What happened to the Salem prize?

Tags: soft-question

Is the Salem prize discontinued? On the [relevant Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_Prize), I don't see anyone since 2018 on there. Why was it discontinued?

Comment: The wikipedia page says the prize is awarded by the IAS, but is this actually correct? Seems to me more like a French thing ... https://lmrs.univ-rouen.fr/fr/content/prix-salem

Comment: According to the announcement for Viazovska (2016), the committee then consisted of Bourgain, Fefferman, Jones, Nikolski, Pisier and Sarnak. The committee in 2018 (the only award after that) wasn't listed, at least in the AMS Notices announcement. Looking at the earlier announcements the committee appeared rather stable. Comparing to, say, 2000 only two members had changed (Wolff and Yoccoz, who both of who passed away, were replaced with Pisier and Sarnak). With so much remarkable working going on by many talented young researchers, it would be a pity if this was/is discontinued.

Comment: Update: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2023/06/21/salem-prize-now-accepting-nominations/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I inquired with the IAS. The Salem prize has not been discontinued, but the pandemic has interrupted operations. It should reopen for nominations later this year.

<sub>You can email me for the full message I received, which includes some personal details.</sub>

Comment: If you're in communication with the IAS, you might recommend that they set up a subpage of ias.edu devoted to the Salem Prize. In today's world, everybody expects that the organization awarding an important prize will have an official website devoted to the prize, listing past winners, the origin and purpose of the prize, the nomination procedure, etc.